# Filtrar objetos no DJANGO - published_date__lte

Tags: sql, python, django

Estou seguindo um tutorial para a modelagem de um BLOG através do **DJANGO** . Em um dos processos, eu crio um objeto com as postagens do site e as ordeno através da data de publicação:

```
def post_list(request):
    posts =  Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'post/post_list.html',{'posts' : posts})
```

Eu sei através do shell que eu possuo ao menos um objeto, pois:

```
Post.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Post: Post1>, <Post: Objeto1 - Postagem>]>
```

Mas quando eu busco verificar o objeto que retorna através da aplicação do filtro aparece:

```
Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date') 
<QuerySet []>
```

Alguém pode me explicar o que significa o parâmetro **published_date__lte** e porque não está retornando o objeto?

Talvez, não tenho certeza, esteja filtrando todas as postagens de agora (`timezone.now()`) e por isso não filtra a minha postagem. De qualquer forma, gostaria que alguém pudesse me explicar melhor esse filtro.

Atenciosamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lte` no django quer dizer "*less than or equal*" ou seja, menor ou igual `<=`. No caso você está filtrando as postagens cuja data de publicação `published_date` sejam menores ou iguais à data e hora atual `now()`.

Isso significa que a consulta não retornará postagens que estão agendadas para ser publicadas no futuro (`published_date > now()`), ou rascunhos que ainda não tenham sido publicados (`published_date NULL`).

Verifique através do shell na sua postagem o campo `published_date` como está preenchido, para resolver o mistério:

```
[p.published_date for p in Post.objects.all()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez seja o fato de voce nao ter publicado os posts que criou no shell. Daí pode fazer o seguinte:

`post = Post.objects.get(<campo_Model> = <valor_atribuido_na_criacao">)` -> Aqui voce pega uma instancia do post que voce criou a partir de um campo que seja caracteristico dele

`post.publish()`  -> Aqui voce publica o post propriamente dito, supondo que sua função publicar no seu model seja publish()